# How does one prove that $\|x\|_2\le \|x\|_1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I intuitively understand that $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}\le \sqrt{x_1^2}+\dots+\sqrt{x_n^2}=|x_1|+\dots+|x_n|=\|x\|_1$. But the thing I'm concerned about is how to prove that $\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}\le \sqrt{x_1^2}+\dots+\sqrt{x_n^2}$?

Comment: Isn't that the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find it easier to argue in the following way: the inequality is true when $x=0$, so assume that $x\neq 0$. Then by the homogeneity of the norms we can assume that $||x||_1=1$. Therefore $|x_j|\leq 1$ for all $j$, so 
$$ ||x||_2^2=|x_1|^2+\dots+|x_n|^2\leq |x_1|+\dots+|x_n|=1$$
and taking square roots yields the desired inequality.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is homogeneity of norms and why we can assume the norm to be $1$?

Comment: Replace $x$ with $x/||x||_1$ on both sides.

Comment: Homogeneity means that $||\lambda x||=|\lambda|\;||x||$ for any real number $\lambda$. So any scalar can be factored out.

Comment: $\|\frac{x}{\|x\|_1}\|_2^2=\frac{1}{\|x\|_1^2}\|x\|_2^2$, but this does not necessarily equal $1$, since $\|x\|_1\ne \|x\|_2$ in general. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Using homogeneity allows you to make one of the norms equal to one, and in this case it's convenient to scale so that $||x||_1=1$ as in my answer.