# Show that $\|x\|_2 \le \|x\|_1$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I am stuck at proving this inequality. I know that $$\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$$
and $$\|x\|_2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2 \right)^{1/2}.$$
I was thinking I should try and prove $\|x\|_2^2 \le \|x\|_1^2$, so something like this:
$$\|x\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i| \right)^2 = \|x\|_1^2.$$
Could this be right and if so, I don't understand the equality used in this proof, why is $\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2 \le (\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|)^2$?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318091/how-does-one-prove-that-x-2-le-x-1

Comment: For **why is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^{2} \le (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|)^{2}$?** see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2 (ab+bc+ca )$$

$$\ge a^2+b^2+c^2$$

if $a,b $ and $c $ are positive.

Comment: I see now! So I could write: $$||x||_{2}^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{2} \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{2} + 2\sum_{i \neq j} |x_{i}||x_{j}| = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|)^{2} = ||x||_{1}^{2}$$

Comment: @Violet Yes yes yes.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Vert x\Vert_2=\Vert \sum x_i e_i\Vert_2\leq \sum|x_i|\Vert e_i\Vert_2=\sum|x_i|=\Vert x\Vert_1,$$
where the inequality used is just the triangular inequality.